# Why are Java arrays fixed length?

Tags: java, arrays, fixed

```
int[] array = new int[10]; // Length is fixed when the array is created.
```

> The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

Why does it have to be so?

Comment: because it was designed like this. If you want to dynamically change the size, use a collection.

Comment: It was designed like this...ok but why?

Comment: what is your own opinion about it ?

Comment: @HichamMoustaid: if you want the why, you'll have to ask those who made the decision.

Comment: @HitchamMoustaid would you like to accept an answer?

Answer (score 12):

As other answers have noted, fixed size is part of the definition, and you'd have to talk to the original authors to find the truth.

But as a general point, it is significantly more complex to implement a variable-length container, and there are a number of strategies for achieving it under the hood (linked list, memory re-allocation ...).

Had the authors defined arrays to be variable-length back in the early 1990s, there would have been several unwanted consequences:

- the core JVM definition of arrays would be far more complex, and all implementations would be forced to provide this complexity at a low level;
- there would be a "one-size fits all" resizing implementation in a given JVM, which might fail to satisfy many use-cases;
- different implementations are likely to introduce large performance variances, which might need additional complicated constraint definition;
- it introduces thread-safety issues around bounds-checking the array, because `a.length` becomes mutable;
- additional linguistic support for expressing expansion => larger language;
- performance implications for array subscripting, potential lack of O(1) indexing;
- unfamiliar territory for C and C++ programmers, who are used to non-extensible arrays (or having such mechanisms provided in libraries);
- casting in stone a variable-length mechanism already adequately handled by higher-level structures (`java.util.Vector` back in the day, and now Java Collections, Guava etc).

To sum up, arrays in the C-language family from which Java was born are broadly expected to be simple tools for building higher-level structures - back then, there was zero surprise at the fixed size restriction. We now have a choice of implementations of such structures (`LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, etc) which provide a selection of runtime behaviours, and most devs use those abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

That's in the definition of Java `array`s:

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type

(see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)).

Use an `ArrayList` for a variable-sized array implementation.