# Is there a way to implement a type-safe vector in Java?

Tags: java, vector, types

I am trying to implement a vector for my coding assignment using Java. I want to put information about the dimension of a vector into its type to make my code more type-safe.

I tried to represent a vector as `int[n]`, but the following code didn't compile.

```
public static int[n] createVector(int n) {
    return new int[n];
}
```

The output of the compilation:

```
src\Main.java:59: error: ']' expected
    public static int[n] createVector(int n) {
                      ^
src\Main.java:59: error: ';' expected
    public static int[n] createVector(int n) {
                       ^
src\Main.java:59: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public static int[n] createVector(int n) {
                         ^
3 errors
```

I think the problem is that all int arrays in java have the same type and I can't specialize it.

Is there a way to do it in Java?

Comment: No you can't specialize a Java array under any circumstances.  Use a class.

Comment: Also, generics do not support values, only types.

Comment: It's not part of the public type information, but Java arrays **are** [fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35846527/2970947).

Comment: To explain the compiler error: you can't specify the _size_ of an array as part of it's type.  I.e. `int[n]` isn't a valid `return` type; `int[]` _is_.   When you _initialise_ an array, you specify its size (so `return new int[n]` is fine, because you're creating one).

Comment: I am not surprised that this code does not compile. What is int[n] in function result type? It must be int[]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make type of the vector [a,b] != type of the vector [a,b,c] you could write something like this:

```html
class Vector<T> {
  private final int dimension;
  private T[] elements;

  public Vector(Class<T> clazz, int dimension) {
    this.dimension = dimension;
    this.elements = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, dimension);
  }
}

class Vector2D<T> extends Vector<T> {
  public Vector2D(Class<T> clazz) {
      super(clazz, 2);
  }
}

class Vector3D<T> extends Vector<T> {
  public Vector3D(Class<T> clazz) {
    super(clazz, 3);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea, but in this implementation, I need to write VectorND for each N, I want to have a generic solution.